# Where exactly to put gradle dependecies in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i created a fresh project in the Android studio and i would like to add this logging plugin.

https://github.com/orhanobut/logger

So i copied all into ProjectDirectory/app/build.gradle go get something like this.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
}
```

But after the rebuild process Android studio is still import wrong class:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

So i think, that dependency was not imported correctly.

How can i do it it the right way please?

Comment: Delete the Logger import. Press ALT-Enter on an instance of the new Logger class you are using, and see what import options you have. Your gradle does not look to be at fault.

Comment: Thanks, i rebuild project and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Well it worked in mine just fine,type Logger. and it will give a suggestion window with 2 types of logger like it always does when multiple import types are available and select the one which belong to your lib.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line `'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'` assumes that you have declared a repository that hosts the artifact it identifies.

If you have declared a valid repository, you've most likely been tricked by auto-import. Remove the import and be sure to select the proper logger import when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

If gradle build completed successfully without errors, then the import was completed correctly. However in your java classess, if you have 2 libraries with the same name (as in your case, there is 2 logger libraries) you can type `logger` then press `ctrl + space` to open a menu that lets you choose which logger library to use.